# rewriterule friendly url with pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to change my rewriterule.
I have a rewrite friendly url:

`RewriteRule ^homepage/([^/]+)$ /home.php?path=$1 [L]`

Which handles URLs of the form `/homepage/gite-di-1-giorno`.

This works. But same page has to handle pagination as well, for example: `/homepage/gite-di-1-giorno?page=2`

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^homepage/([^/]+)$&page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^homepage/([^/]+)$&page=([0-9]+) /home.php?path=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

but `$_GET["page"]` is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you just need to add the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag to your original rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^homepage/([^/]+)$ /home.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` flag appends (merges) the query string on the original request (if any) with the query string you are setting in the *substitution* string. So, a request of the form `/homepage/gite-di-1-giorno?page=2` is internally rewritten to `/home.php?page=gite-di-1-giorno&page=2`.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa